# Effective ways to get rid of smell in basement from drain?

Tags: drainage, smell

**Background**

So this weekend I got to have all the fun of unclogging a clogged drain. The drain was from a kitchen sink but I was able to go through a lower access point and run a motorized snake through to clear the clog. In the process of opening the access cap and not realizing that there was a bunch of water still inside.. well let's just say that it created a big mess of water shooting out!

The basement is unfinished so surfaces are cinder blocks / concrete floor.

**Problem**

So we got the clog taken care of and wiped everything down on our hands and knees with rags, soap, and water. We have the two only available windows open in the basement but there isn't a ton of airflow possible due to lack of basement windows. I am wondering if anybody has better suggestions to get rid of the stink left over?  Everything is capped off again so the source should be taken care of.

Comment: bleach the heck out of everything to reset the funk growth.

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely why fans exist. One in, one out. You might also sprinkle baking soda (or a freshening product which includes same) on the raw concrete to absorb odor.

The key is getting things dry, though. Bacteria can't survive long if things are dry. A dehumidifier would help with that.

If all else fails, rent an ozone neutralizer.